# Status of RFD groups and $C^*$-algebras

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, oa.operator-algebras

Motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410186/examples-of-locally-compact-groups-that-do-not-admit-enough-finite-dimensional-r) and its great answers, I become very curious to know what do we know about RFD (residually finite dimensional) groups and $C^*$-algebras, e.g. do we know how these properties behave under various constructions (amalgamated product etc.). Are there some survey articles on these topics?

Comment: These seem like two separate questions ... maybe delete the second paragraph and ask it separately?

Comment: @NikWeaver Done.

Comment: To my knowledge, there aren't any survey articles on the topic. However, here's a link to the slides of a talk of Kristin Courtney where she survey's a lot of the theory https://kristincourtneycom.files.wordpress.com/2019/05/ecoas_2018.pdf . I would also check the papers [K. Courtney and T. Shulman, Free products with amalgamation over central C*-subalgebras] and [T. Shulman, Central amalgamation of groups and the RFD property].