# Does every locally compact, simply connected group admit enough finite dimensional representations?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Given a simply connected locally compact group $G$, is it true that $G$ admits enough finite dimensional representations (over any field and not necessarily continuous) to separate points in $G$, what about over $\mathbb{C}$ and we require the representations to be continuous?

Again, this question is a follow-up of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410186/examples-of-locally-compact-groups-that-do-not-admit-enough-finite-dimensional-r), and it seems better to ask it separately here.

Comment: Ben Wieland answered this in the negative in a comment to the original question, assuming continuity. This assumption is not needed really, by the work of Borel-Tits on "abstract homomorphisms".

Comment: The smallest counterexample is the universal covering of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$, which is even contractible (homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^3$). Possibly it is easier to prove non-linearity (without continuity) for the 2-fold covering of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ for larger $n$. These contain f.g. non-residually-finite subgroups, but I'd like an elementary argument for this.

Comment: Please see the article https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1980-259-02/S0002-9947-1980-0567087-9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connected Lie groups whose points are separated by the finite-dimensional complex representations are exactly the linear Lie groups, for instance by Th. 5.3 in [Beltiţă and Neeb - Finite-dimensional Lie subalgebras of algebras with continuous inversion](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm185-3-3).